# Webform in mvc, jQuery and ajax

Tags: jquery

Struggling with this issue: I have a form filled out and submit the form. Once I click on the browser's back button I get to the original pre-filled form, but noticed a field isnt populated anymore.

Can we retain information/data on a form using the browser's back button ?

Or is this a jQuery limitation?

Any ideas come in handy,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

which is the field ? Example:  If its an input field, you need to pre-populate it with a value="" param with the the $_POST global arrya

Comment: ok, then what you do is get the value from the POST variable and depending on the value pass in the "selected" param in the option. If you can throw in your code, it would be easier to explain.

Comment: Let me try to clear it a bit more: This is a radio button on the form- (after selected) , I can view the selection, along with other data entered, and then save these to retrieve a review page (summary)that navigates to another page after submission. On this last page, hitting the browser's back button takes me to the form. The data initially filled in the form all shows except for the text from the radio button option . I have spoken with some people and they mentioned that its hard to retain this data expecially with the browser's back button - Is this true ? Is there a workaround it ?